# How to make a html page from CKeditor

Tags: javascript, html, express, ckeditor, backend

I am creating a News Blog Website. For composing new blog in the website, I am using Ckeditor as Rich Text Editor. I am using ejs as my view engine, I am using node.js and also express.js

```
<form action="/compose" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Post</label>
            <textarea name="postBody" id="editor">Start Writing Here.</textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
            .then(editor => {
                console.log(editor);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>
```

Now I am using this data and creating a post page

```
<%= content %>
```

but when I am opening my post website, I am getting my post content in raw HTML format as shown below

```
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<i> Quae maxime</i> dolore necessitatibus iste aliquid dolorum in nostrum repellat rerum atque?</p>
```

how can I get it in plain text with all the tags applied to it.
For eg:- I want like this

**Lorem ipsum** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.*Quae maxime* dolore necessitatibus iste aliquid dolorum in nostrum repellat rerum atque?
Please help me, sorry for my english or my silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<%- content %>
```

instead of this:

```
<%= content %>
```